# Python Next Prime Number While Loop Infinite

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have made a code for generating a next prime number, for example if I input the number 4 it will give me the input 5 or 25 it will give me the input 29.

The problem I get is that I can't seem to get the while loop to close, it goes on forever, is there anyway to close this while loop so that it does iterate infinitely.

I have also tried using breaks to end the code but then the code doesn't output the right input. For example after putting a break the code then would input 27 as a prime when I inputted 25. This is wrong since I know 27 is not a prime number.

```
X = int(input())
Prime = True

while Prime:
    for i in range(2,X):
        KK = X % i
        if KK == 0:
            X+=1
        else:
            print(X)
            Prime = True
```

Comment: You need to set `Prime` to `False` somewhere in loop.

Comment: You never set `Prime` to `False` anywhere

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the loop will never end.

Below is a naive solution for reference. 
 Obviously, incrementing the running variable by 1 and checking if it is prime is a bad strategy. 
 Also, there are better prime number checkers out there.

```
def isPrime(num):
    for i in range(2, num//2): 
        if (num % i) == 0: 
            return False
    return True

X = int(input()) 
while not isPrime(X):
    X += 1
print(X)
```